# How to get an url of javascript link using python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jsf

In the following website:
http://dgp.cnpq.br/dgp/faces/consulta/consulta_parametrizada.jsf

Using Selenium, I clicked in the button "Filtros", selected Sudeste as "Região", and selected Rio de Janeiro as "UF", then I clicked "Pesquisar". And it generated a list.

In this list, I need to copy the link,
but the link is generated by script

```html
<a id="idFormConsultaParametrizada:resultadoDataList:0:idBtnVisualizarEspelhoGrupo" 
    href="#" 
    style="width:16%" 
    onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(
            document.getElementById('idFormConsultaParametrizada'),
            {
                'idFormConsultaParametrizada:resultadoDataList:0:idBtnVisualizarEspelhoGrupo':'idFormConsultaParametrizada:resultadoDataList:0:idBtnVisualizarEspelhoGrupo'
            },
            '_blank'
        );
        return false
    ">
    Culturas e saberes urbanos e as modalidades de descrição e de representações visuais das cidades</a>
```

I tried right click, but it returns the main link.
It only generates the link, that I want, with the action of the OnClick.

And the link generated looks like: `http://dgp.cnpq.br/dgp/espelhogrupo/2612134540655635`,
it's always `dgp.cnpq.br/dgp/espelhogrupo/` + numbers

I would like to know, if there's a way to run the script from the onclick event and then get these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look for these numbers somewhere else on the page - they may be contained in meta tags.
2. If not, you can use regular expressions to find the desired digits like this:

   dgp.cnpq.br/dgp/espelhogrupo/(\d+)

You need find this number on HTML page and get it with RegExp. If page hasn't number - check Ctrl + Shift + U -> Network -> XHR.

Comment: I have looked all the code of the page, and I couldn't find these numbers, they're generated in that script.
How can I use this expression to find the correct numbers for that link ?

Comment: You need find this number on HTML page and get it with RegExp